# Bug nas acentuações data.sql - SpringBoot e Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

O banco postgres está em UTF-8, porém quando insiro pelo data.sql, acentos e cedilhas não são interpretados.

Exemplo do meu data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO professor (name, login)
VALUES ('Requião', 'requiao');
INSERT INTO subject (name, professor_login)
VALUES ('Raciocínio Lógico', 'requiao')
```

Meu application-properties:

````
#Read CSS and JS
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**

#Data sources
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbookdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin

#Data requirements
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:data.sql
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;

#Data logs
logging.file.name=logs/logs.log
logging.level.root=OFF
logging.level.com.ucsal.springbook.service.LogService=DEBUG```
````

Saída:

```
RequiÃ²o - RacicÃnio LÃ3gico
```

Deveria ser:

```
Requião - Racicínio Lógico
```

Answer (score 1):

Para quem está com este problema, eu mesmo consegui resolver. Basta adicionar o código abaixo no seu application.properties:

`spring.sql.init.encoding=UTF-8`